# Global Property Changed object casting results in null (in C#)

Tags: c#, object, casting, inotifypropertychanged, invalidoperationexception

I am having some trouble with initializing a new variable as the object being sent by the global property changed. I have two classes `BeltConfiguration` and `BeltProperty` (both classes have `INotifyPropertyChanged`). I have a `globalpropertychanged` method in the `BeltConfiguration` class as seen here.

```
        private void BeltProperty_GlobalPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            BeltProperty validBelt = sender as BeltProperty;
            if (validBelt != null)
            {
                this.Validation = validBelt.Validation;
            }
            switch (e.PropertyName)
            {
                case "Value":
                    this.Validation.ValidState = ConfigurationValid.Unknown;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Validate");
                    break;
                case "ConfigurationInvalid":
                    this.Validation.ValidState = ConfigurationValid.False;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Validate");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

In the `BeltProperty` class, I call this with `OnGlobalPropertyChanged("ConfigurationInvalid");`
However, when I call it, no matter what I do, `validBelt` always results in being `null`. I looked at the object sender by stepping through the code and it says that the declaring method, `GenericParametersAttributes`, and `GenericParametersPosition` threw an exception of `System.InvalidOperationException`. I don't know if that has anything to do with why `validBelt` won't accept sender as `BeltProperty`. Thanks for any help or advice you can give me.

This is where I called BeltProperty_GlobalPropertyChanged in the Belt Property class.

```
    private ConfigurationValidation _Validation = new ConfigurationValidation(ConfigurationValid.Unknown, "", "", null);
    /// <summary>
    /// Stores information as to wether this belt property is valid or invalid, and the details.
    /// </summary>
    internal ConfigurationValidation Validation
    {
        get { return _Validation; }
        set {

            _Validation = value;
            if(_Validation.ValidState == ConfigurationValid.False)
            {
                OnGlobalPropertyChanged("ConfigurationInvalid");
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A global on property change that runs for any instantiated object of this type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name"></param>
    static void OnGlobalPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        GlobalPropertyChanged(
            typeof(BeltProperty),
            new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a safe cast here:

```
BeltProperty validBelt = sender as BeltProperty
```

When `validBelt` is `null` after this assignment it means sender cannot be cast to an instance of `BeltProperty`.

Looking at your calling code it looks like you are not passing an instance of `BeltProperty` into your event handler.

Assuming `GlobalPropertyChanged` is your `PropertyChangedEventHandler` delegate change your `OnGlobalPropertyChanged` code to this:

```
/// <summary>
/// A global on property change that runs for any instantiated object of this type.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name"></param>
static void OnGlobalPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    GlobalPropertyChanged(
        this,
        new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name)
    );
}
```